# How do I solve "pythoncom39.dll could not be located error"?

Tags: python, pip, anaconda

[image: Warning screenshot.]

It has started appearing ever since I installed Anaconda on my PC. It doesn't affect anything and when I press "Ok" it goes away. But it is quite annoying and I would like to know the reason. It has only appeared when I try to run a development server in Django or try to install python modules using pip. Is there any way to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It happens because anacondaa3\Library\bin\ in this folder pythondicom39.dll has crashed you need to replace it with a new file

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that dll file might be corrupted. Just replace, and then try it. You can download the pythoncom39.dll files from the following link

https://freeonlinestudies.com/python-dlls/